# Why am I getting a System.InvalidCastException when using a ViewCellRenderer in iOS Xamarin Project

Tags: uitableview, mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, tableview

I'm using a ViewModel first approach to Xamarin.Forms and have begun the process of writing my own Bindable TableView (I imagine plenty of people have). The project is going well and I'm already rendering cells in the UI based on my on CellViewModel types and wanted to move to the next phase of adding the 'effects' of things like 'Disclosure' and 'Checkbox' accessories to cells. It transpires that these things only really make sense in iOS projects so I found myself looking into ViewCellRenderers specifically in iOS.

In order to apply the appropriate accessory on the cell, I needed to create a class to do so:

```
public class AccessoryItemCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
```

which itself is relatively simple. It takes the BindingContext of the Xamarin Cell and then applies the accessory as appropriate:

```
var viewModel = item.BindingContext as TableCellViewModel;

if (viewModel != null )
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            if (viewModel.Accessories == CellIndicators.Disclosure)
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
            else if (viewModel.Accessories == CellIndicators.DisclosureDetail)
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
            else if (viewModel.Accessories == CellIndicators.Detail)
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
            else if (viewModel.Accessories == CellIndicators.CheckMark)
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        }
```

At least I thought it was straightforward, as when the base.GetCell call gets made, it turns out my reusableCell property is null and this I am *assuming* is causing a System.InvalidCastException which then blow up. It's not very obvious to me what is causing it, the only real stack trace I get is this:

```
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Cells\ViewCellRenderer.cs:28
```

Is it because somehow my cell doesn't have a reusable id? How do I provide one if this is the case? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And which one is line 28?

Comment: It's not my code, the stack trace is referring to the UIKit code in the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer. The line that blows up in *my* code is the base.GetCell line.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry! What is most likely the case is that you are trying to render a ViewCell when it really is something else. What are the cells you are trying to apply this on?

Comment: Well, my renderer is defined at the assembly level to work on TextCell's at the moment: [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TextCell), typeof(AccessoryItemCellRenderer))] So, I'd expect the renderer to only be called appropriately for that type of cell. It's the whole 'null' reusable cell thing that gets my Spider Senses tingling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mention that you're registering this AccessoryItemCellRenderer for TextCell. In the AccessoryItemCellRenderer you are inheriting from ViewCellRenderer which is for ViewCell. TextCell does not inherit from ViewCell and cannot be cast as a ViewCell and that's most likely where the exception is coming from.

Comment: wow you have Eagle Eyes, good spot! Right on the money. I had assumed that all cell renderers inherited from ViewCellRenderer (I was following an example that used a custom cell for this case). Thank you!